Unit Test MS Teams Bot
I have created a Teams Bot/Message Extension App in typescript. I want to unit test its functionality. Like the the onMessageActivity or handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask. Please Help on this.
I have checked the docs as in the docs it has include the dialogs for bots which I'm not using.

Can you please share the doc you are referring currently?

@ChetanSharma-msft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
